# PuTTY password access denied

Tags: putty

I try to log in with PuTTY as root, but when I type in the password it says *access denied*.

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you verify you're connecting to the correct host? Is e password correct, or did you e.g. Change keyboard layouts? Can you log in using other users? Is SSH root login enabled or disabled?

Comment: As an addition to @DanielBeck's questions: Is root login enabled on the server? What's the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` look like?

Comment: I agree something like "I can log in just fine to that host with the user/pass that I know, using the hypervisor" but closing this question is too far.

Answer (score 28):

There are only four potential problem I can think of (most of which have been covered already):

You're not connecting to the right server.

- If you're using an IP address, check it.
- If you're using a host name, verify that it's pointing to the right IP address and/or try the IP address instead.

You're not entering the right username.

- The fact that you have root access doesn't mean you can actually log in as root. It only means that you have an account with root privileges (normally via sudo).
- If you're not entering the username manually, make sure **Connection → Data → Auto-login username** is actually set to *root*.

You're not entering the right password.

- Check the password you're entering.
- Verify that <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is disabled.
- Verify that PuTTY uses the proper keyboard layout.
- Instead of Ctrl+V, try copying the password, then click inside the console and right click.
- If you use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, make sure **Terminal → Keyboard → AltGr acts as Comopse key** isn't checked.
- If none of the above works, clear the field **Connection → Data → Auto-login username** (assuming it is set) and enter the password in the username field to verify it gets entered correctly.

Root access is disabled.

Some SSH servers can disable SSH logins for certain users and may even disable root logins by default. If you're using Open SSH server, you have to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure that it doesn't contain one of the following lines:

```
    PermitRootLogin no
    PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Both result in a simple *Access denied.* error, although they permit you to enter the password. The latter only allows root logins when authenticating using public keys.

To permit root logins, remove the corresponding line or replace it with the following:

```
    PermitRootLogin yes
```

See [man sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) for further information.

Comment: The root access was disabled for me, great answer!

Comment: The 4th option worked for me as well. My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file did not contain either of the two lines that were mentioned, however I added the `PermitRootLogin yes` line to my file anyways and it worked. Make sure you restart your SSH service after making any modifications to that file (`service ssh restart`), so that they take effect.

Comment: Amazing answer and amazing comment by Steph! I was stuck and thought my goose is cooked, as I have a deadline for tomorrow... Using linux Alpine for vm... I also could not connect, didn't have the two PermitRootLogin things but I added one with 'yes'. Also worth mentioning that in my case, I had to restart sshd, not ssh. Happy days! Thank You!

Comment: "Instead of Ctrl+V, try copying the password, then click inside the console and right click" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was fail2ban that I had installed.

Solution: edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

The line with the entry `ignoreip =` must be edited. Put your IP / CIDR / DNS name in the box and the login should be possible again.