# How can I solve "access denied" when I login via putty?

Tags: ssh, putty, winscp, session, mobaxterm

I want to running SDK. The docs like this :

1. For Running SDK you can use (MobaXterm or Putty)
2. Create an SSH Session with the following data:

   Address/Host : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

   Port : 2222

   Username : Secret

   Password : secret

So I try to access it use Putty like this :

[image]

Then I click open and input username and password, the result like this :

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

**Update** :

I try `Secret@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` too. But it does not works

I have tried more than 10 times and failed. I tried using MobaXterm and winscp and that also failed. I'm confused to solve this problem

Comment: @HazardousGlitch software development kit

Comment: No, sorry, I mean what SDK are you using? Where are you getting the login info from?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Seems it use java. This is used for chatbot. We get info login from the vendor. our vendors made it for us

Comment: I would contact the vendor to verify the info and have them try connecting. It's possible the info wasn't set up correctly. Generally we can't help with Access Denied other than telling you what I and Thomas said.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch ok i will do that. previously I thought I made a mistake in the configuration

Comment: If you followed their directions exactly and are getting Access Denied then it's likely something on their end. Good luck!

Comment: @HazardousGlitch ok they gave me documentation and I just followed their documentation. I will contact them to make sure

Answer (score 1):

It depends if your can access the host without this SDK via putty?

If not check first this:
[PuTTY password access denied](https://superuser.com/questions/539139/putty-password-access-denied)

If it is possible to access the host via putty, then you have only the problem to pass authorization?!

Best option would be to use a SSH Private Key (Use as example PuttyGen to create a key) and let pagent running on background with the unlocked private key. Then there is no password based logon needed.

This is a detailed instruction: https://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty

If your really wont to pass the passwort, you need to call putty like this:

```
putty -load MySession -pw MYPASSWORD
```

or without a session (use the default session params):

```
putty -P 2222 user@host -pw MYPASSWORD
```

Comment: I do not know. I will try that later.  I just followed their documentation

Comment: could you resolve the problem with those hints?

Answer (score -1):

I too Had a same problem then i Found that i had not done the port forwading so that i can access it from the public network,so make sure your port is opened for the public access which ever port you are using for ssh.

Comment: The fact the original author got an 'access denied' is a clear indication the server he is connecting to actually responded and rejected the credentials. Implying that it isn't caused by blocked ports.

Comment: You are  more then welcome to try ssh on closed port and know the error buddy

Comment: I get an error message which clearly states 'connection refused'.